# Git requests token instead of password

Tags: windows, git, github, github-for-windows

for every operation I do in my git, I need to insert my username + security token that came when I enabled the 2fa.

I dont want to copy the key everytime for every operation I do, it is very time consuming, I want to insert something I remember like my password.

How can I arrange that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these commands to cache the token.

Set git to use the credential memory cache:
git config --global credential.helper cache

Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds):
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'

Then you only have to fill out the token once every hour.

See more info here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache